# How to read hindi text from the excel sheet in java?

Tags: java, excel

I have a requirement where I have to read hindi text from an excel sheet in java. when I read the hindi text from excel and When I try to print the hindi string , only a set of ??? are displayed.

Can anyone please help me with this. 
It will be really helpful. Thanks.

my code for reading --

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();                        

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            //System.out.println("nextrow"+nextRow);
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                System.out.println("Cell value =="+cell.getStringCellValue());
                //System.out.print("@@"+cell.getCellType());
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    Cell cell1 = cell.getRow().getCell(0); 
                    Cell cell2 = cell.getRow().getCell(1); 
                    System.out.println(cell1);
                    System.out.println(cell2);
                    if(cell1 != null && cell2 != null){
                        String col1 = cell1.getStringCellValue();
                        String col2 = cell2.getStringCellValue();
                        sentences.add(col1+"_@@@_"+col2);
                    }
                    break;
```

but when I try to print the readed data it displays ??????. please refer below -

```
??? ???? ????????? ?? ???????? ??? ?????? ?? ??????
```

Comment: show us, what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Please see the edited post for code

Comment: Sorry it's still not clear. You mean `System.out.println(cell1)` prints only `?` instead of hindi characters? If so, where `System.out.println` is printing? Is there some IDE? Which? Or does it simply print to a terminal? If so, is it a Windows CMD terminal? If the latter, then Windows CMD will simply not have glyphs for the hindy characters. That does not mean, that the characters are not there. Try creating a text file from the cell's string content and then look into that file.